# Changing The slider Effect (JS/jQuery) to Slices Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, slider

Hi everyone i have site I'm designing, but i need a effect to be change in the slider to getting sliced effect.

Current code & Site:

http://www.summerskymusic.net

```
// options
            var accordion = $(this);
            var items = accordion.find(':has('+options.slider+')');

            items.each(function(){
                var item = $(this);
                var opener = item.find(options.opener);
                var slider = item.find(options.slider);
                opener.bind(options.event, function(e){
                    if(!slider.is(':animated')) {
                        if(item.hasClass(options.activeClass)) {
                            if(options.collapsible) {
                                slider.slideUp(options.animSpeed, function(){
                                    hideSlide(slider);
                                    item.removeClass(options.activeClass);
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            // show active
                            var levelItems = item.siblings('.'+options.activeClass);
                            var sliderElements = levelItems.find(options.slider);
                            item.addClass(options.activeClass);
                            showSlide(slider).hide().slideDown(options.animSpeed);

                            // collapse others
                            sliderElements.slideUp(options.animSpeed, function(){
                                levelItems.removeClass(options.activeClass);
                                hideSlide(sliderElements);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                if(item.hasClass(options.activeClass)) showSlide(slider); else hideSlide(slider);
            });
        });
    };
```

Example of What i want to achieve site:
http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/

Thank you.

Comment: If you've found a slider that does what you like why not use it? Especially since it's free and comes with a tutorial.

Comment: You're right, didn't thought of it, i solved it with Revolution Slider. Thank you for reminder.@88mpg

Comment: No problem and good luck! I've had good experiences with Revolution Slider, I think it'll do everything you need.